# Qt 5.0.2 and OpenGL

Tags: qt, opengl

I want to use the newest Qt 5.0.2 (also Qt Creator) together with OpenGL 3.3+. The official website of Qt contains following links:

- Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 485 MB)
- Qt 5.0.2 for Windows
  32-bit (VS 2010, OpenGL, 476 MB)
- Qt 5.0.2 for Windows 64-bit (VS
  2012, 500 MB)

Does it mean that using OpenGL  with the last package (VS 2012 compiler) is impossible ?

Comment: Check the edit to my answer, I unintentionally misled you a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>All of those builds are perfectly capable of running OpenGL 3.3+ code. The "OpenGL" signifies that the package is build so that QtQuick2 uses OpenGL instead of ANGLE, and it applies only to the QtQuick2 scenegraph. A decision made because of the fact Windows 8 doesn't support OpenGL in "metro" mode.</strike>

Sorry for the initial incorrect answer, it appears that the way ANGLE support was implemented renders the entire build useless for desktop OpenGL. I myself never used ANGLE and this whole thing strikes me as a terribly bad idea, but what can you do...

And BTW, if you are interested into OpenGL programming, you might want to get Qt 5.1 RC, which has a lot of new OpenGL abstractions and other goodies that make OpenGL programming faster and easier. It also offers more "out of the box builds" including an [OpenGL based MSVS2012 x64 one](http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.0-rc1/qt-windows-opensource-5.1.0-rc1-msvc2012_opengl-x86_64-offline.exe).

Comment: That's good news, but in Qt 5.0.2 OpenGL wrappers seems to be suited to OpenGL ES 2.0 and don't provide a complete modern OpenGL functionality, right ?

Comment: OpenGL2/GLES is just the minimum compatibility layer for QtQuick, the Qt GL abstractions are not limited to OpenGL 2/ES. In 5.1 there are GL function classes you can get for a specific GL version, so you can also have compile time safety and conformance to the GL features of the version you target. Check "OpenGL with Qt5" and "Modern shader based OpenGL techniques" from http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLizsthdRd0YzYe5T3Txgg7TUGVi-ijq4d for more info

Comment: That's not correct. 1) With an ANGLE build of Qt, you are going to get OpenGL ES2 and that's it. Use the "OpenGL" builds to get full desktop GL. If a build for your platform/compiler is not available, then compile from sources. 2) OpenGL3, or OpenGL2 + FBO extension, or OpenGL ES 2 are the minumum requirements for QtQuick2.

Comment: @peppe - I will check this out and edit my answer if necessary.

Comment: @peppe - Qt does have a history of some terribly bad ideas. I assume this is due to the integration of OpenGL in QtGui. Building QtGui for ANGLE probably cripples normal GL support. ANGLE should only be targeted by the scenegraph rather than QtGui...

Comment: I know that ANGLE is bad for many reasons, and personally don't use it. But I do understand that for many people there's no choice due to bugged GL drivers (...or if using Qt on Metro becomes a reality). Moreover, these days the OpenGL enablers live in QtGui; the SG just uses them as they're exposed. Things will start to get better when we'll always have both ANGLE and Desktop GL builds for any given platform.

Comment: I think the "buggy GL drivers" is an urban legend, and pretty much a thing of the past. 99% of the "pc" GPUs that ship today have pretty good drivers. The reason for ANGLE is mostly Windows 8, and M$'s decision to further downplay OpenGL in favor of its own proprietary graphics API. M$ $uck$...

Answer (score 2):

That means that this package is build with ANGLE, which only supports OpenGL ES 2.0, but works on a wide range of computers including those with crappy OpenGL drivers.